# Typescript error : A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a simple decorator in typescript:

#### EnumDecorator.ts

```
import { EnumsHelper } from './EnumsHelper';

export function Enums(constructor: Function)
{
    constructor.prototype.TT = EnumsHelper.TT;
    console.log('injected');
}
```

But I get the error : `A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods`

Answer (score 0):

This is a C# error message.

This can happen if you created a file as `C#` (by saying 'New class') and then rename it to `.ts` without changing the build action.

[image]

Change the `Build Action` to none to fix it.